# How do I slow down the emulation in VMware and make it go "proper fullscreen" for Windows 3.11?

Tags: emulation, windows-3.x, 80486

I have just managed to find and install my native language versions of MS-DOS 6 and Windows 3.11 in a virtual machine, just as I had on my first computer: an IBM 486 DX2 66 MHz.

VM software: VMware Workstation 15 Player.

I've got it working, and I'm very happy for that, but there's two issues:

1. It's going at lightning speed. When I type "win" in MS-DOS prompt after starting it up, I can only see the Windows logo for a split second before I see the Windows 3.11 Program Manager, fully loaded. The way I remember it, that Windows logo "splash screen" is supposed to show for many seconds until the GUI gradually loads up. How do I slow it down? I've already looked in the CPU settings for the VM, and baffingly, it lacks any option to "simulate 486" or anything like that. Not even a field to enter any kind of cryptic number. How is it done?
2. The GUI uses 640 × 480 pixels, just as I remember it. However, even in fullscreen mode, it looks like a little square in the middle of my 1920 × 1080 screen. It could easily be "2×2" as big without being upscaled in any way. (Yes, there would still be black bars on all four sides.) I don't see any options anywhere to make it scale up either, but even if there were, I wouldn't want that. The "VMware tools" only seem to be available for Windows, and when I try to install them anyway, there is no `D:` (CD-ROM) drive, neither in Windows or DOS. So that's probably not it.

How do I solve these two frustrating problems so that I can actually see what I'm doing and immerse myself in nostalgia and preferably never return back to the present?

Comment: This seems to be a question about modern software, VMware, and not about retrocomputing *per se*.

Comment: Sounds to me as if the OP wants to recreate a "retro" experience. Does it not count as "retro" if it's emulated?

Comment: Well, it goes at super speed. It's not simulating the speed of the computer I used to use, so it's a distorted nostalgia. I want it to be exactly like it was. I picked the right amount of RAM and HDD storage and everything in detail.

Comment: Going 'super speed' is natural. VMware is not an emulator to recreate an old machine and especially not meant to support nostalgia. VMware is a hypevisor offering a virtual environment to run multiple environments on the same machine. It's task is to **NOT** slow it down, giving all power to whatever it is hosting. VMware is about giving maximum power to whatever is running inside. So by giving small amounts of RAM or HD results simply  in a modern machine with small amounts of RAM and HD, not a slow machine. You might want to use a PC-Emulator instead.

Comment: DosBox can run win3.11 and has a speed option

Comment: Buy an old computer which can have a modern SSD drive added.

Comment: This guy has collected a set of drivers to give a better experience with Win 3.1 with modern machines.  I have not tested it.  http://www.scampers.org/steve/vmware/#31pack

Comment: I think this question falls within the remit established by https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/15334 in that it asks about tuning a platform (which happens to be an emulator) to work well with retro software, as opposed to tuning an emulator to work well with its host environment. One might as well ask a very similar question whether there’s an equivalent of a Turbo button for modern physical hardware.

Comment: @user3840170 except that VMware is not an emulator and not intended to be slowed down. He asks for hacking a function in modern software which it is not intended for. The Issue he has is not rooted in any old software not is it related to any original/old software, but entirely within the new software, which is not intended to work as a retro environment at all. So the cites Meta post does not fit.

Comment: VMware is a program that replicates the functionality of a certain amount of PC hardware, enough to be able to run software designed to run directly on that hardware. How is it not an emulator? That it’s not designed to recreate the experience of using old hardware does not disqualify the question. It just means it can be answered with ‘use something other than VMware’. How is installing Windows 3.11 in VMware any different from installing it on modern bare hardware, which isn’t ‘intended for’ such use either? The latter would certainly be on-topic.

Comment: @user3840170 how is VMWare an emulator? It runs everything natively and directly on the host hardware (except for a few privileged instructions in dynamic translation mode when virtualization isn't available). Simulator, emulator, hypervisor are different things

Comment: It is an emulator because it emulates. Whether the guest code is run directly or interpreted is immaterial. This is like splitting hairs over what counts as a ‘transpiler’ versus a ‘compiler’ — it just doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 15):

VMWare is not an emulator these days, but a hypervisor.  Windows 3.1 is running directly on the hardware with nothing underneath it, just fenced in by hardware-level protection and translation.  If you want to slow it down, you'll have to eat up cycles with a busy task, or slow down your processor some other way.

Another option would be to use an emulator like [PCem](https://pcem-emulator.co.uk/) which aims for timing accuracy of real 8086 through 80586 PC compatible machines, though it may not have some other features of VMWare you need.

Comment: Would it have killed them to include the option to simulate slowness? They cannot possibly be so naive to think that: 1. Everyone uses it for "as fast as possible" business applications only. 2. That it's even something good to run these old systems faster than they were designed for... which it obviously isn't. No, I don't buy this answer. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Rothberg - an option to simulate slowness isn't as obviously easy as you think.  There's the relative speed of I/O devices, for one.  Plus, VMWare isn't in business to sell to hobbyists who want a "retro" experience.  The people they are _selling_ their products too - who are willing to pay $$$$ - aren't using them to boot Windows 3.1 and see the logo screen in all its glory.  This answer is useful because it points you to an _alternative_ that you could use.

Comment: @davidbak Well, I don't trust PCem, which I haven't heard of until today, and what's more, its website royally pisses me off by deliberately leaving out any "About" section or even short paragraph or even slogan. It doesn't say what it is, and makes the visitor *guess*. I hate that.

Comment: @Rothberg But that's exactly what VMware is about, giving as much computing power as possible to a guest system. A typical use  case ist o run a production environment on a developer machine to test a new version. Or to run a certain application only available under a different OS, or to run some software that works only under an older  OS version. In all these cases one wants to have  as much power as possible. Why wait as long as one did years ago?  Long story short: _The answer is spot on and you're simply trying to use the wrong tool._ Get a PC-Emulator. They offer what you want.

Comment: @Rothberg Their target group does not need that.  If I were to use old software today in a professional setting I would like it to run as fast as the machine allowed.

Comment: There also exist a couple of active forks of PCem named [86Box](https://86box.net/) and [VARCem](https://www.varcem.com/) that you can consider.

Comment: `VMWare is not an emulator these days` in fact VMWare has never been an emulator

Comment: @phuclv The early versions of VMWare predate x86 virtualization extensions and were implemented as a JIT x86 emulator.  That's been dropped for 15+ years now, though.

Comment: @RETRAC are you sure? Without virtualization both VMWare and Virtualbox uses dynamic translation which simply replaces priviledged instructions in the instruction stream and doesn't do any JITting, otherwise performance would be terrible. No idea about VMWare but Virtualbox still supports that nowadays so you can still run 32-bit VMs without virtualization

Comment: @phuclv Perhaps we have different definitions of JIT.  To me, such dynamic translation is JIT.

Comment: even if you think patching a few instructions in the instruction stream is JIT then VMWare is still not an emulator. It still supports running 32-bit guests on hosts without virtualization nowadays and yet not a single other person calls it an emulator. Emulator means emulating the entire machine and translating every single instruction to that target. Because VMWare doesn't emulating and translating all instructions, it has no means to limit the speed even  in [Software-based virtualization mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#SWBASED)

Comment: @phuclv To me, if the entire instruction stream is being scanned and retranslated by software on the fly, this is effectively dynamic translation/emulation even if most of the output is just copied straight through.  The Wikipedia article you linked even mentions this is a note of contention, apparently.  I suppose we'll just have to disagree on definitions.

Answer (score 8):

You might consider DOSBox (free).  It is more oriented towards emulating retro hardware, and has some speed control options.  It tries to 'figure out' what the speed control should be, but there is a manual setting you can also use if that fails.

Additionally, it does have a scaling feature (which I personally prefer over going full-screen anyway -- going full screen does some DirectX stuff and moves my existing open windows all around).

Comment: Apparently [Windows 3.1 will run inside of DOSbox](https://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=3210&letter=W).

Comment: oh thanks @StarCat! I was going to give it a go myself, but I only have floppies (of WfW), and I couldn't be bothered to dig up a floppy drive to make images (if those floppies are even still intact magnetically).